# How to implement a twodimensional matrix with a onedimensional matrix

Tags: java, arrays

I have my first Java exam in a month and need help with one of the excersises in class.

### The problem to solve is the following (I hope it still makes sense because I just translated it from German to English):

In the class Matrix2D implement a two-dimensional int-matrix with the help of a one-dimensional int[] which is called “elements”.

Implement the following methods:

Matrix2D(int numRows, int numColumns) -> Constructor of the Matrix2D with the given size.

void set(int row, int column, int value) -> Saves int value on the right position(row, column) of the matrix

int get(int row, int column) -> Returns the value of the position (row, column)

So this is the question. Our lecturer gave us the "solution" to this question, but really I don't quiet understand it.

### The "solution" looks as followed:

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhVvv.png)

Can anyone help me understand this better ?

Comment: It is just indexing games in a large 1D array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a visual example that may help.  Assume your 2D array is 2 rows deep and 3 columns wide.  I have labeled each element in the 2D array and its 1D representation with the index of the 2d array it represents (assuming zero-based offset).  So you are just taking each row of the 2D array and "flattening" it.  Based on the getOffset() function in the example, so getOffset(1,2) maps to the 1D index of

```
index =  1*3 + 2 = 5
```

[image]

Comment: @elly thanks.  glad it helped.  Please tag the answer if you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty straight forward. So instead of creating a 2d matrix the code is saving the data as a single array. Stay with me, I will explain:

Imagine a 2d matrix of 4*5 now carefull understand what does 4*5 means. it mean that I have a collection of 4 arrays and each array is of size 5.
so if the matrx is

```
int[][] matrix = {{1,2,3,4,5}
                  {6,7,8,9,10},
                  {11,12,13,14,15},
                  {16,17,18,19,20};
```

As you can see here its 4 rows and 5 colums. Now think for a moment you extract each array, merge them and put it side by side. How that would look?

```
int[] matrix = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,29};
```

But how did we do that the indexes are all wrong. Notice now if you have access matrix[2][3] what does that mean. Simply put I want to access the 3rd array(0 indexing so 0,1,2) and in 3rd array I want the 4th value(0 indexing so 0,1,2,3). so how do we do that

```
public int get offset(int row,int column){
  /*skip the 0th and 1st array and than go to the 4th element*/
  /*understand columnSize as number of elements in each array that we need to skip*/

  int skippingPart = row*columnSize;
  int newIndex = skippingPart+column;
  return newIndex;
}
```

So the matrix[2][3] in 2d array becomes array[13] (we skipped the first two elements so 10 elements(0-9) than we added 4 more to get the element so 13)

Comment: Thank you! This is pretty simple. I  took the definition of the problem too literal and thought I really have to construct a two dimensional matrix ( int  [ ]  [ ] 2DMatrix).

Comment: woudn't the element at array[13]  be 14 for your example ?

Comment: nope so it will be 
[0,1,2,3,4]
[5,6,7,8,9]
[10,11,12,13,14]

sp [2][3] is 13 please like that answer if that helps